# Authenticating as an Application

Tags: php, facebook

Where you type these things?:

```
curl -F type=client_cred \
     -F client_id=your_app_id \
     -F client_secret=your_app_secret \
     https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token
```

In other words, how I'll do it in PHP? Or manually?
[source](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PHP [curl function](http://php.net/curl) or use the PHP+Javascript example on the page you link to...